Rebalancing strategy with PineScript executes 2 orders on rebalancing day
I'm trying to write a PineScript 5 strategy that rebalances its portfolio once a week, for research purposes. For some reason, the strategy executes 2 trades per week. I can't figure out why it executes the second if statement, at the end of the trading day.
//@version=5
strategy("MA Crossover with Dynamic Rebalancing", shorttitle="MA+Rebalancing", overlay=true)

// Inputs
shortEMALength = input.int(21, title="Short-Term MA Period")
longEMALength = input.int(55, title="Long-Term MA Period")
lookback = input.int(100, title="Volatility Lookback")
tradingCapital = input.int(10, title="Trading Capital")

// Moving averages
shortMA = ta.ema(close, shortEMALength)
longMA = ta.ema(close, longEMALength)
plot(shortMA, color=color.blue, title="Short MA")
plot(longMA, color=color.orange, title="Long MA")

// Position sizing
dailyReturns = close / close[1] - 1
historicalVolatility = ta.stdev(dailyReturns, lookback) * math.sqrt(lookback)
positionSize = 10 * historicalVolatility // This is just an example value

// Entries
if ta.crossover(shortMA, longMA)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, qty = positionSize)
if ta.crossunder(shortMA, longMA)
    strategy.close("Buy")

// Rebalance on Mondays
rebalanceDay = dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
if rebalanceDay and strategy.opentrades > 0
    oldPositionSize = strategy.position_size

    if positionSize > oldPositionSize
        strategy.order("Buy", strategy.long, qty=positionSize - oldPositionSize)
    else if positionSize < oldPositionSize
        strategy.order("Buy", strategy.short, qty=oldPositionSize - positionSize)
        // the strategy executes this trade as well, at the beginning of the next day


